# HM-10 Arduino Bluetooth Module Not Working

Tags: android, arduino, bluetooth, hm-10

I am currently trying to set up my HM-10 Bluetooth module with my Arduino and when I do this I am faced with two problems. When I connect the Bluetooth module I cannot upload any code to the Arduino as it just gets stuck on "uploading" forever until it crashes. When I disconnect the module I can upload code perfectly fine. The other problem which is probably connected to the other one I cannot connect to the Bluetooth module with my phone. I have used the passwords 1234,0000 and 123456 and they all just say couldn't connect? The AT commands don't do anything as I cannot upload anything to it.

[bluetooth setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iL3VK.jpg)

[bluetooth 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLPXE.jpg)

[bluetooth 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ak6mf.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I connect the Bluetooth module I cannot upload any code to the Arduino as it just gets stuck on "uploading" forever until it crashes.

The Arduino IDE uses the main serial port on the Arduino UNO to upload new sketches (programs). Your pictures indicate, however, that you are using that serial port to communicate with the Bluetooth module.

Instead, use the [SoftwareSerial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) library to communicate with the bluetooth module - and leave the RX/TX pins free. The SoftwareSerial library will allow you to select different pins: see example [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SoftwareSerialExample).

> The other problem which is probably connected to the other one I cannot connect to the Bluetooth module with my phone.

Well ... Have you even uploaded the required program to the board yet? If not it's premature to examine this issue. Verify that you can upload the program first.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have gotten it to work with the SoftwareSerial. :D